# Average of word embeddings with TF-IDF score

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf, word2vec

I have been developing a python script to classify if an article is related to a body text or not. For that I have been using ML (SVM classifier) with some features, including average of word embeddings.

The code for calculating the average of word embeddings between the list of articles and bodies is the following:

```
word2vec_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
setm = set(word2vec_model.index2word)

def avg_feature_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set):
        #function to average all words vectors in a given paragraph 
        featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
        nwords = 0
        for word in words:
            if word in index2word_set and word not in stop:
                try:
                    featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word])
                    nwords = nwords+1
                except:
                    pass
        if(nwords>0):
            featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
        return featureVec

def doc_similatiry(headlines, bodies):
    X = []
    docs = []
    for i, (headline, body) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(headlines, bodies))):
        headline_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(lemmatize_str(clean(headline)).split(), word2vec_model, 300, setm)
        body_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(lemmatize_str(clean(body)).split(), word2vec_model, 300, setm)
        similarity =  1 - distance.cosine(headline_avg_vector, body_avg_vector)
        X.append(similarity)
    return X, docs
```

It seems like the average word2vec is being calculated correctly. However, it has worse scores than the TF-IDF cosine alone. Therefore, my idea was to group these 2 features, by that means, multiplying the TF-IDF score of each word to the word2vec.

Here is my code to do that:

```
def avg_feature_vector(words, model, num_features, index2word_set, tfidf_vec, vec_repr, pos):
        #function to average all words vectors in a given paragraph (with tfidf feature)
        featureVec = np.zeros((num_features,), dtype="float32")
        nwords = 0

        for word in words:
            if word in index2word_set and word not in stop:
                try:
                    a = tfidf_vec.vocabulary_[word]
                    featureVec = np.add(featureVec, model[word]) * vec_repr[pos, a]
                    nwords = nwords+1
                except:
                    pass    
        if(nwords>0):
            featureVec = np.divide(featureVec, nwords)
        return featureVec

def doc_similatiry_with_tfidf(headlines, bodies):

    X = []
    docs = []
    for i, (headline, body) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(headlines, bodies))):
        docs.append(lemmatize_str(clean(headline)))
        docs.append(lemmatize_str(clean(body)))
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm='l2',min_df=0, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, stop_words=stop, sublinear_tf=True)
    sklearn_representation = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

    for i, (headline, body) in tqdm(enumerate(zip(headlines, bodies))):
        a = (clean(headline))
        headline_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(nltk.word_tokenize(a), word2vec_model, 300, setm, vectorizer, sklearn_representation, 2*i)
        a = (clean(body))
        body_avg_vector = avg_feature_vector(nltk.word_tokenize(a), word2vec_model, 300, setm, vectorizer, sklearn_representation, 2*i+1)

        similarity =  1 - distance.cosine(headline_avg_vector, body_avg_vector)
        X.append(similarity)

    return X, docs
```

My problem is that this method is getting awful results and I don't know know if there's some logic that explains that (because in theory it should have better results) or if I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Also, I am open to new solutions to solve this problem.

Note: There are some functions used there which I didn't post the code since I thought they were not necessary. If there is something you don't understand I am here to explain it better.

Comment: Do you want to calculate weighted tf-idf value for a paragraph?